# Safe/good way to wrap c++ new/delete for multi-threaded environment

Tags: c++, malloc, interrupt, new-operator, delete-operator

I was having some issues with new/deletes occurring on different threads (TI F28379D) that were causing the program to lock if an interrupt occurred in the middle of allocating or deleting. I didn't want to wrap every instance of new/delete with a macro that disables and enables interrupts, as it felt like a lot of duplicate code. My solution was to create two functions that have the appropriate macros around the new/delete.

```
void *create_array_pointer(uint16_t count, size_t size, char *variable_name) {
    //create the array (inside where interrupts are disabled
    uint16_t interrupt_settings = __disable_interrupts();
    void *ptr = new uint16_t[count*size];
    __restore_interrupts(interrupt_settings);
    check_allocation_throw_error(ptr, variable_name);
    return ptr;
}

void delete_array_pointer(void *ptr) {
    uint16_t interrupt_settings = __disable_interrupts();
    delete[] ptr;
    ptr = NULL;
    __restore_interrupts(interrupt_settings);
}
```

This works for primitive types. However, I realized today that this is a bad solution for c++ classes that have default constructors/destructors, as the constructor or destructor will never be called automatically.

Is there some way to make sure the constructors/destructors are called, without going back to wrapping every call?

Comment: Have you considered templates? `template <class T> void delete_array_pointer(T *ptr)` gives you the type information needed for the destructor to be called automatically. Same goes for `create_array_pointer` while you're at it.

Comment: Override `operator new`? (and new[] and delete and delete[])

Comment: Are you unable to use *smart pointers*?

Comment: @Galik, the TI compiler only supports up to C++03, so no smart pointers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am assuming you are in an environment where you can't use *containers* or  *smart pointers*. Otherwise I would recommend returning `std::vector` or `std::unique_ptr`.

You can use templates to retain the **type** of the objects you are creating whilst still being *generic*.

Also you may want to consider a `RAII` way to manage your *interrupts* as they will be exception safe as well as being generally safer and easier:

```
template<typename T>
void check_allocation_throw_error(T*, char const*) {}

// This will disable interrupts on creation and re-enable them
// when it goes out of cope. This means if you reach the end
// of the function OR if an exception is thrown the interrupts
// will be re-enabled regardless.
class interrupt_disabler
{
public:
    interrupt_disabler(): settings(__disable_interrupts()) {}
    ~interrupt_disabler() { __restore_interrupts(settings); }

private:
    interrupt_disabler(interrupt_disabler const&) {}
    interrupt_disabler& operator=(interrupt_disabler const&) { return *this; }

    uint16_t settings;
};


template<typename T>
T* create_array_of(uint16_t count, char const* variable_name)
{
    T* ptr = 0;

    // create a scope where interrupts are disabled
    {
        interrupt_disabler lock(); // enabled at end of scope OR if new throws
        ptr = new T[count];
    }
    // interrupts enabled automatically here

    check_allocation_throw_error(ptr, variable_name);

    return ptr;
}

template<typename T>
void delete_array(T* ptr)
{
    interrupt_disabler lock(); // enabled at end of scope
    delete[] ptr;
}

struct MyType {}; // any old type

int main()
{
    MyType* mytype = create_array_of<MyType>(10, "wibble");

    delete_array(mytype);
}
```

Comment: I'll have to look closer at this. Of note, this is an embedded device so RAII is out, and the compiler only supports C++03 (see my comment above).

Comment: @AdamJones But `RAII` still works in `C++03` desn't it?

Comment: `RAII` should still work. I guess I've shied away from using it, because most embedded discussions consider it to have too much of a performance penalty (although this could be due to exceptions, and not `RAII` itself).

Comment: @AdamJones In your code comments you mention throwing exceptions so I assume they are enabled on your compiler?

Comment: Nope. No exceptions, they are not enabled. The `check_allocation_throw_error` function simply checks if the pointer passed is still null (meaning it wasn't allocated properly), prints a message through the UART, and locks the processor in an infinite loop - insane, but I'm doing it just to make extra sure I don't try to work on a variable/object that wasn't allocated properly.

Comment: @AdamJones Well `RAII` is not *as* important without exceptions but it is still useful in making sure things like interrupts are turned back on at the end of the current scope.

Comment: Sorry, I'm really rusty on operator overloading. `interrupt_disabler& operator=(interrupt_disabler const&) {}` throws an error, because there is no return value. But I'm not sure what should be returned there.

Comment: @AdamJones My mistake. I forgot when I converted it from `C++11` to `C++03` and I added an empty body. Should be fixed now.

Comment: @AdamJones Correct me if I'm wrong, but how does RAII become a performance penalty? It is a compile time construct. It would also allow you to reimplement `unique_ptr`

Comment: @PasserBy, I have no idea. It's quite possibly a misunderstanding on my part.

Comment: @Galik. Well, I can compile the class by itself just fine. However, testing it out with both the create and delete in a real example, throws `no instance of function template "create_array_of" matches the argument list argument types are: (uint16_t, char *)`. I know the passed parameters are correct, and the return is type `volatile exp_input*`. I'll try digging some more, because I'm sure there's something simple I'm missing.

Comment: @AdamJones My guess is you didn't add the template parameter? I have posted an example of how to call the function in the `main()`.

Comment: Yup, I should've realized that. Success. And I realized in the process that you fixed the scope issue with `T* ptr`. Thank you. That was very helpful. Even though I haven't fully tested it, it's good to see a possible solution.

Comment: @Galik. Minor update. Although I haven't looked at the assembly yet, it seems that using `interrupt_disabler` doesn't work as intended. I think this is maybe because the disable and restore interrupts are not functions, but are macros for something else. However, when I wrap the new/delete with the macros, using the new template functions, it works well.